# How to stop Entity Framework Core 6.0 connection to Oracle 12c timing out when connecting/updating database?

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core, oracle12c

I'm trying to use Entity Framework Core 6.0 to connect to my employer's Oracle 12c server. As per Oracle's instructions, I have added the `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore` package, but when I try to connect using the DbContext I've created, I get the following error once the connection times out:

```
2022-07-25 15:29:49.014946 ThreadID:1   (ERROR)   OracleDatabaseCreator.Exists() :  OracleException.Number: -1000
2022-07-25 15:29:49.022577 ThreadID:1   (ERROR)   OracleDatabaseCreator.Exists() :  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Connection request timed out
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleDatabaseCreator.Exists()
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Connection request timed out
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String 
contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Connection request timed out
```

I've tried adding a `Connection Timeout=1200` parameter into the connection string; this solves the error above but a new error results:

```
2022-07-25 15:26:25.234429 ThreadID:1   (ERROR)   OracleDatabaseCreator.Exists() :  OracleException.Number: -6403
2022-07-25 15:26:25.240231 ThreadID:1   (ERROR)   OracleDatabaseCreator.Exists() :  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Network Transport: TCP transport address connect failure
 ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x80004005): Network Transport: TCP transport address connect failure
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.ValueTaskSourceAsTask.<>c.<.cctor>b__4_0(Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskToApm.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at OracleInternal.Network.TcpTransportAdapter.ConnectIterate()
   at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor)
   at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.Connect(String tnsDescriptor, Boolean doNAHandshake, String IName, ConnectionOption CO)        
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String instanceName)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleDatabaseCreator.Exists()
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Network Transport: TCP transport address connect failure
 ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x80004005): Network Transport: TCP transport address connect failure
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.ValueTaskSourceAsTask.<>c.<.cctor>b__4_0(Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskToApm.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at OracleInternal.Network.TcpTransportAdapter.ConnectIterate()
   at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor)
   at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.Connect(String tnsDescriptor, Boolean doNAHandshake, String IName, ConnectionOption CO)        
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String instanceName)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String 
contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Network Transport: TCP transport address connect failure
```

Also have tried tweaking some of the parameters in the main C# file (such as command timeout) to no avail.

My OnConfiguring method is as follows:

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) => options.UseOracle(@"User Id=<Work User ID>;Password=<Password>;Data Source=ANALYTICS;");
```

I'm still able to connect to the database using SQL Developer, DBeaver as well as through Python and the Oracle Instant Client using the cx_Oracle package, so it seems like an issue with .NET Core. I'm running .NET Core 6 on Windows 10 21H2. Anyone got any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: If .NET 6 had a problem, people would have noticed. On the other hand though, Oracle drivers *always* cause problems. They are overweight, buggy and have significant problems that Oracle simply refuses to fix. "Asynchronous" methods for example aren't. They're blocking calls that return `Task.Completed` at the end. That's why people use alternative drivers whenever possible.

Comment: Have you tried connecting using ADO.NET directly to the database? The stack trace you posted shows. the problem is caused in `OracleConnection.Open()`. Can you replicate the problem if you open the connection yourself? What does the connection string look like? Is it the correct one? Does Oracle allow connecting from that machine, with that connection string?

Comment: 12c is *very* old and already out of support. The latest Oracle drivers probably can't connect to it at all.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've tried doing that and still get the same Connection request timed out error. It probably is because 12c is old - unfortunately that's what we're stuck with at the moment. I was going to use this just for testing purposes (eventually the app I'm developing would get its own Oracle DB) as I wouldn't need to create a VM to run Oracle locally but it looks like I'll have to do that. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You can try with older driver versions until you find one that works. Oracle connectivity can be pretty tricky though, depending on whether you connect directly or use ORACLE_HOME, whether you use a fat or thin client. Especially when talking about an 8 year old version.

Comment: The oldest version in [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core#versions-body-tab) is 2.18.3. Can you use that? After testing that you can jump forward eg a year to see if the driver still works etc, until you find the latest driver that works

Comment: 3.19.80 worked  - however it seems that 12c is just too old to work properly with EF Core as I was now getting other errors relating to table definition etc, which I am not getting with 21c. Hence, I've moved over to a local 21c XE server for development purposes.